# Como invocar una variable public static int en c#

Tags: c#

Estoy realizando un cuestionario, y necesito sumar las variables de varios formularios. Primero las declaro como `public static int`, y las llamo desde un formulario que ejecuta una gráfica. Esto es parte del código que ocupo para invocar mis variables. Pero al momento de jecutar la grafica no me sale nada

```
int economico = Testya.eco1;
int salud = Testya1.salud;
int sociales = Testya2.sociales;
int exactas = Testya3.exactas;
int biologicas = Testya4.biologicas;
int arte = Testya5.arte;

string[] series = { "Ciencias Econòmicas-Administrativas", "Ciencias Sociales y Humanidades",
    "Ciencias Exactas e Ingenierìas", "Ciencias Biològicas Agropecuarias", "Arte, Arquitectura y Diseño", "Ciencias de la Salud" };
int[] puntos = { economico, sociales, exactas, biologicas, arte, salud};
chart1.Palette = ChartColorPalette.Pastel;
chart1.Titles.Add("Resultados");
for (int i =0;  i>series.Length; i++)
{
    Series serie = chart1.Series.Add(series[i]);
    serie.Label = puntos[i].ToString();
    serie.Points.Add(puntos[i]);
```

Comment: Y cual es la pregunta?

Comment: ah rayos! es que no me sale nada en la grafica

Comment: Que es esto `Testya.eco1` ?? Puedes hacer el debug poniendo un punto de interrupción en esta linea `int economico = Testya.eco1;` y comentando que sucede

Answer (score 1):

Puedes declarar una variable publica estática en la clase **Program** de la siguiente forma:

```
    namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    {
        static class Program
        {
            public static int variable1 = 0;
            /// 
            /// The main entry point for the application.
            /// 
            [STAThread]
            static void Main()
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }
        }
    }
```

Y la puedes mandar llamar desde cualquier formulario del programa de la siguiente manera:

```
    Program.variable1 = 10;
```

De igual forma puedes declararla en cualquier clase y haciendo referencia a la clase sin necesidad de instanciarla:

```
    public class Clase1
    {
        public static int variable2 = 0;
    }
```

Y mandarla llamar así:

```
    Clase1.variable2 = 10;
```

**Nota:** Creo que es la respuesta a tu pregunta, sin embargo el uso de variables estáticas generalmente no es una práctica recomendada, aquí te dejo un vínculo a una discusión al respecto: [Why are static variables considered evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil)

Answer (score 0):

y por qué no usas mejor `propiedades`?

al igual que estas haciendo con las variables publicas estaticas, puedes crear unas propiedades asi:

```
public class Testya
{
  // Un atributo privado
  private int economico = 0;

  // Oculto mediante una "propiedad"
  public int economico
  {
    get
    {
      return economico;
    }

    set
    {
      economico= value;
    }
  }
}
```

Luego desde el otro formulario solo tienes que llamarlas asi:

```
Testya ejemplo = new Testya();

//asi le asignas valores
ejemplo.economico= 6;

//asi lo puedes leer/mostrar
Console.WriteLine(ejemplo.economico);
```